# Cannot get photo from gmail contact

Tags: asp.net, google-api-client

I am trying to retrieve photo of a gmail contact using following code using ASP.Net C#

```
public void DownloadPhoto(ContactsRequest cr, Uri contactURL)
    {

        Contact contact = cr.Retrieve<Contact>(contactURL);

        Stream photoStream = cr.GetPhoto(contact);
        FileStream outStream = File.OpenWrite("test.jpg");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[photoStream.Length];

        photoStream.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(photoStream.Length));
        outStream.Write(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(photoStream.Length));
        photoStream.Close();
        outStream.Close();
    }
```

But when I run this code on line

```
 Contact contact = cr.Retrieve<Contact>(contactURL);
```

I get following exception:

**"Parsing failed"**

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 1.

ContactUri is something like this:
*https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/[my-email-address]/1*

Can someone please help me with this.

Thank you